# Dynamically adding a comment section to Google Sites announcement page

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

I have a script that allows a user to create an announcement post on a Google Site, without requiring edit access. I would like to add a comment section [like this one](https://sites.google.com/site/mori79/html-gadgets/how-tos/comment-form-board#discuss) at the end of every post that a user adds.

I'm wondering if this is possible and if so, can someone guide me in the right direction? I have about a year of experience with google apps script but on this one, I'm feeling a little stuck wondering which direction to go or if it's even possible.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Google Sites classic are no longer editable and the the Google Sites Service of Google Apps Script was deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

Follow these steps:

1) Go to the page or page layout that you want to add comments
2) Select the item "More"
3) Select the sub-menu item page configs 
4) Check the allow comments checkBox

If you do this for the page layout every new page will allow comments. If you do this only to the current page this will be the only one affected.

It's not possible to do this wth users that does not have edit permissions.
A workaround in this case is to create an apps script do be insert in the pages. Use ScriptDB to store the comments and use the current page call as key in this DB.
Best,

Comment: This only works for a user if they have edit access to the site. I'm wanting anyone within view access to be able to comment on the page and this will only be possible with an outside app I believe.

Answer (score -1):

This only works for a user if they have edit access to the site . . .

Comment: Please, don't add signature links to your posts. You can add those on your profile page.